# How to remove outline from entire web site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, outline

I want to remove all the outline from the inputs and buttons and controls of the whole website and I tried with this below but it doesn't work? (I am using bootstrap if that matters)

```
*{
    font-weight:lighter;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: `*, input, button {outline:none !important;}`

Comment: Using `!important` is not nessecary.

Comment: You *must* include your custom css **after** bootstrap's. To be sure you're overriding it.

Comment: I do this. Without !important this doesn't work, but when i include !important buttons have no outline, but input=text do

Comment: @v.g. that's because you need to add `*:focus` selector too.

Comment: so like this? *, input, button, :focus { outline: none !important; } ?

Comment: Try  `*, *:before, *:after { outline-style: none !important}`

Comment: @zer00ne no, once again the text inputs have outline

Comment: Throw inputs in there as well.+

Comment: What is the syntax for this?

Comment: It's a group of universal selectors that cover any generated content as well.

Comment: so is this correct *, *input:before, *input:after { outline-style: none !important} because it also doesn't do the trick